# why are these two intuitive ways of understanding division equivalent?

Tags: arithmetic, intuition

The elementary school example of division, say 12:4 is saying that you have to share out 12 cookies to 4 kids. However, another (only slightly less intuitive) way would be to ask how many times 4 "fits" into 12. I am not a native English speaker but I guess that's the intuition behind the (mostly American ?) expression and notation of dividing "4 into 12".

My question is the following. What would be an intuitive way to explain why these two intuitions of division are in fact equivalent?

Comment: Teachers always teach the first way of understanding division, ie by dividing, as it's most intuitive, but the way we do division calculations is with the other interpretation of seeing how many of the second number go into the first number. Kids get super confused by this, as it's never explained by teachers. It's a real problem.

Answer (score 4):

You hand out 12 cookies to four kids. The cookies are not chocolate chip cookies, as they first appear to be -- they are oatmeal raisin cookies. The kids throw the cookies back into the jar. How many cookies does each kid throw back into the jar?

Comment: Not immediately obvious and a bit roundabout as it requires already performing the division.

Comment: Four kids have cookies. Upon discovering they are oatmeal raisin cookies, they put them back and let the next four kids suffer. The next four kids discover 12 total cookies. By how many cookies do each of the next four kids suffer?